# Accessing associations of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

assume you have a case like this

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
  belongs_to :record_label

  def albums
    return 5
  end
end
```

Is it possible to access the albums relationship without using the Artist#albums, since it has been overridden?

This can happen with mixins or other random cases, it is mostly helpful for tests.  Then you can say Artist#albums is actually a relationship to albums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`association`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L152), and retrieve its scope:

```
a = Artist.first
a.association(:albums).scoped
```

Note that `association` is not documented, and neither is the object it returns ([`ActiveRecord::Associations::Association`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb)), which means [`scoped`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb#L86) isn't documented either.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask - why do you need to override `#albums`?  This has the disadvantage of violating the Principle of Least Surprise - everybody would expect `#albums` just to return the artist's albums.

Otherwise, I would access them simply by `Album.where(artist_id: artist.id)`.

Comment: Answered with edit above and the where only works in cases where the relationship is two way assume RecordLabel does not have any knowledge of Artist then where would not work